# java.lang.NumberFormatException - Can't find where the error is

Tags: java

I am getting this message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:454)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at fdc.programming.VendingMachine.InsertMoney(VendingMachine.java:70)
    at fdc.programming.VendingMachineDriver.main(VendingMachineDriver.java:30)
Java Result: 1
```

I had been trying to work out, how to do a validate loop so that only positive integers can be accepted and I gave up for now, but I did not change anything and put everything back as it was before messing around. Now when I try to enter a number it gives the above error but there are no errors in Netbeans that I can use to figure out what is wrong! Please be aware that I have only done one basic module in Java for college ;)

My code is:

```
public class VendingMachine
{
String sinsertMoney, sinsertMoney2; // Money inserted value for parsing into int
String productName;     // Name of product

int insertMoney, insertMoney2;  // Money inserted by customer (int = pence)
int price;                  // Price of products on sale
int changeLeft;         // Change left from inserted money after selection

int again;          // variable for deciding program repeat

DecimalFormat pence = new DecimalFormat("#p");  // Format display output for pence

public void InsertMoney() {
    String soption;             // Variable for machine operation
    productName = " Nothing";
    insertMoney = 0;        // Default inserted money initialised to zero
    insertMoney2 = 0;   // Default additional inserted money initialised to zero
    price = 0;          // Initialising money variables

    // Vending machine welcome dialog

    soption = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
            "============================================"
            + "\nWelcome to the College Vending Machine!" 
            + "\n============================================"
            + "\n\nOptions: i for insert money, s for select item, q for quit."
            + "\n\n============================================");

    if ("q".equals(soption)) {   // If user chooses q: quit 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Have a Nice Day!");
        System.exit(0);     // terminate application
    }
    if ("i".equals(soption)) {   // if user chooses i: insert money
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                "=============================" 
                + "\nPlease enter some money (in pence)" 
                + "\n=============================");   // Inserting money
        insertMoney = Integer.parseInt(sinsertMoney);   // Parsing for calculations
    }
    if ("s".equals(soption)) {    // if user chooses s: select item
    }
}
```

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null` You are trying to parse a `null` String. Check if `sinsertMoney` is `null`.

Comment: what is sinsertmoney variable? where it is define and initialized?

Comment: where `sinsertMoney` is declared and initialized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see where you've declared `sinsertMoney` but it looks like you've forgotten to assign the result of your call to `JOptionPane.showInputDialog` to something, hence why that value is still null when you try to parse it.

Try this:

```
sinsertMoney = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
    "=============================" 
    + "\nPlease enter some money (in pence)" 
    + "\n=============================");   // Inserting money
insertMoney = Integer.parseInt(sinsertMoney);
```

Comment: Ah, must be my lack of sleep lol I added the variable initialisation I forgot but thanks for picking the error, now it's working again...and I can get back to the headache of validation :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the entered value in `sinsertMoney` like:

```
sinsertMoney = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
        "=============================" 
        + "\nPlease enter some money (in pence)" 
        + "\n=============================");
```

And also implement null check on the `sinsertMoney` for **cancel operation and empty strings**.